# How to unify Python Pyramid views for handling Ajax/html form POSTs

Tags: python, ajax, forms, post, pyramid

I have some HTML forms in my Python Pyramid application. I'd like them to work via AJAX when JavaScript is enabled and when JavaScript is disabled. Now I use different views for AJAX and normal form posts, but the code seems almost the same for these functions, except response. I use view class like this (class body):

```
def ajax_ok(self, msg):
    return Response(body=msg)

def ajax_error(self, msg):
    return HTTPInternalServerError(body=msg)

@action(xhr=True, renderer='json', name='ftp')
def ftp_ajax(self):
    log.debug('View: %s', 'ftp (ajax)')
    if 'form.submitted' in self.params:
        try:
            self.config.save(self.params)
        except:
            return self.ajax_error('some error')
        else:
            return self.ajax_ok('ok')

@action()
def ftp(self):
    if 'form.submitted' in self.params:
        try:
            self.config.save(self.params)
        except:
            self.request.session.flash('error; ' + msg)
        else:
            self.request.session.flash('success; ' + msg)
    return {'content': render('templates/ftp.pt', {'ftp':
                                                    self.config.ftp})}
```

I need to handle error if any and show them in html.
Maybe I should use [finished_callback](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#using-finished-callbacks) or my own renderer which will send different response for different request type??

Comment: it looks like only 1 of 4 code paths is the same right now so I'm not sure what you're hoping to consolidate. I'd say it's good enough to handle all of the `save` functionality in a common place and do error handling independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
@action(name='ftp', renderer='templates/ftp.pt')
@action(xhr=True, renderer='json', name='ftp')
def ftp_ajax(self):
    log.debug('View: %s', 'ftp (ajax)')

    # CODE

    if request.is_xhr:
        return JSON
    else:
        return something for template
```

But if you do really great you could have something like that:

```
@action(name='ftp', renderer='templates/ftp.pt')
@action(xhr=True, renderer='json', name='ftp')
def ftp_ajax(self):
    log.debug('View: %s', 'ftp (ajax)')
    my_values = dict()

    # Code

    return my_values
```

but to be honest in your current code, the code isn't very similar since in you don't return the same thing and in one case, you push to flash some infos and in the second you return some things.

In that case, it's better to keep thing separated than to merge everything together. But if you can separate and return the same data, you can stack `@action` together.

Comment: I like your solution but now I see I had 2 problems and the second is how to manage exceptions in views (in same situation - when posting html and AJAX forms).

Comment: Instead of raising exception or returning exceptions you can use something like that. `dict(ok=False, message="error message")` when you have an error and `dict(ok=True, content=dict(...))`

Comment: note that json renderer will render correctly an Object that you can inspect, and the template can use also those values. I'm pretty sure that you can add a beforerender event that will check for ok and is.xhr and throw an exception if needed with the message contained. It might not be the best but it's possible to do there

Comment: This technique tends to cause problems in certain browsers where they will cache the json result. Since the URL is the same for both the json result and the html, when the html is requested it will see that the data is already cached and return the json, causing problems.

Comment: he can pass a dummy parameter just like jquery does to make every request unique. While it's also possible to explicitly tell the browser not to cache the request. http://site.com/javascript/info?_=[random]

Comment: but honestly I'd make all my views render only html or javascript/json and write an API to return only json/xml (data). mixing things is sure not making anything easy.

Comment: exactly, it's a red herring that sounds awesome until you try to do it.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel What does *red herring* refer to?

Comment: I mean that it sounds attractive but unless you carefully set cache/vary headers and (possibly other things) your browser may cache the json as html or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have one method `ftp` and inside of it check whether `request.is_xhr` is true to render the correct error/response.